# Android ".xml is out of sync. Please refresh" after transferring

Tags: android, xml

I started to create my own applications but needed to use a different computer after some time. So I transferred my workplace folder to a new machine and set up eclipse,sdk,etc..(and adjusted all the needed paths in a right way). But now when I try to work with transferred projects all xml files show the following ".xml is out of sync. Please refresh". Please help!

Comment: Have you tried recopying the xml files only and overwriting them?